# How to set custom width of bar in NDV3 Discreate bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, nvd3.js

Am trying to build vertical bar chart using nvd3 charts.

Problem :
   If chart has single record, bar width reaches 3/4 of the chart width.

Question :
   How to change width of the bars in Discrete bar chart?

Have attached chart please guide me..

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the source [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/discreteBarChart.js#L147).  You'll see that the width of the rectangle is calculated based on the number of items using [rangeBand](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_rangeBand).  There doesn't appear to be a way to set the width of the rectangle though the library's API.

If you didn't want to patch the library, you *could* create additional fake bars with zero data and provide a label formatter that would return an empty string if the value was zero, but that assumes zero is not a valid number in your data set.

Comment: It's a nice solution @WolfgangCodes! But I can't figure why someone want a chart with only one data.

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli, I'm afraid only Mohan can answer that one.

Comment: sometimes, you are drilling down different level of a hierarchical data and leaf or intermeidate level could have only one item. In that case, chart ended up like this

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwing code to set the width

```
dispatch: {
    renderEnd: function (e) {
        d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").attr('rx', 4).attr('ry', 4).attr('width', 15)
    }
}
```

or you can use

```
groupSpacing : 0.57,
```